# Search for page title

Tags: 7, views, search

I want to search for page name.

I have a title of page news and events. if i search event. i want news and event page will come on search results. when i click on that news-events page will open.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What is the difference from the normal drupal search behaviour?

Comment: it doesnt show pages

Comment: your search yield no result or not displaying one particular content type in search result?

Comment: its not content type.. its page.. i need to search by title not content

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one: https://www.drupal.org/project/search_by_page

Hope this is what you require.

Comment: this is not working